Are scans accepted as US visa photos?
The requirements of what must and must not be on a US visa photograph are quite clearly stated online. But I am not so sure about quality, there are statements made on blurriness and grain but I cannot judge at all whether my pictures fulfills them.
There is not photographer near me so I would have to travel quite a distance and spend a hefty sum to have my picture taken professionally. Trying to take a selfie with my phone also did not go so well. What I have instead trie is to take a picture a Photo Booth and scan that at 600 dpi. Unfortunately the result still looks somewhat grainy, see picture attached. Will this still be acceptable?


I don’t know how you scanned it, but it’s blurry and way too light IMHO.

I don't know about US visas, but I've had 100% success with a number of e-visas using a tripod-mounted camera, timer and taking a photo against a neutral background (an inside wall). I followed the rules of composition, format, resolution and cropped and adjusted brightness & contrast only. Professional photographers are not necessary if choose to have someone else do it  - outfits that do passport photos sometimes offer digital delivery as an option. In the US (yes, I know that's not an option in this case) some Walmarts will do that cheaply.

The requirements for a US visa photograph are given here: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/photos.html
Nothing is said prohibiting scans of photographs.
You have a number of options other than professional photographers, selfies and photo booth scans. The obvious one is to get someone else to use your phone/camera to take a photo of you, eliminating the problems of trying to arrange both yourself and the camera in an optimum composition. You can also get someone else to take a photo of you using their phone or their camera .
Note that different US visas have slightly different requirements, including some that require prints.

Every time I've been waiting in a US consulate for a visa interview there have been other people being told to go and get new photos because they ones they had provided were not up to standard. As you can guess, the place they were being sent to (in the same building) wasn't cheap...

@Doc: Check photos, you see many errors which should be easy to correct. A professional helps getting light and to take the photo correctly. But not required. Since 20 years I do not use professional services. -- In any case, to consider: the photo is not for application to be a model (but people seems to care so much on hairs and ignoring the basics: looking up/down, being too high or low or on side, to many shadows, or glare of flash). Photo doesn't need to be perfect nor good, just it should follow few points which are used to distinguish people (again: nothing to do with hair and beard)

I will probably ask someone else to retake the picture to be sure anyways but this seems to be the best answer possible without actually applying.

Not really an answer to your question if your original image will be accepted, but it is simply too bright and can easily be improved by adjusting the brightness in an image editing software:


To be clear, you increased contrast and saturation, right?

I don't know if that answer's still valid, but once upon a time this would have been specifically forbidden by the US.  See Is it legal to photoshop the background of a visa photo for more details.

@ave Technically speaking, I stretched the histogram of the image. I did not modify the saturation. Brighter pixel appear less saturated than they technically is, so in technical terms, reducing the brightness of an image usually also make the colours appear and look more saturated.

@MadHatter Correcting the brightness and contrast of a scan is not something you would call 'digital retouching', which is apparently what is/was forbidden. The answer links to a now non-existing page, so I don't know more about what was written on that page than the few quotes in the SE answer.

I'd certainly call it digital retouching, but I accept it doesn't really matter what either of us thinks it is: it matters what the state department thinks it is.  I saw they'd broken their internal links (I hate organisations that do that) and lacked the time to chase down the new version of the guidance, so I posted what I could: a warning that, once upon a time, USG certainly had a policy that, depending on the reading, might well have forbidden the practice you advise.  What it has now, I can't say.

OK, the new guidelines are at https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/photos/digital-image-requirements.html , and say that "photos must not be digitally enhanced or altered to change your appearance in any way".  That's just as useless as the previous guideline, because it's still ambiguous: does it mean must not be (enhanced) or (altered to change...), or must not be (enhanced or altered) to change...?  I guess my advice would be to avoid the issue by rescanning the photo until it's right, instead of editing the scan.

@MadHatter Retouching is in the context of photography a pretty well defined technical term and it does not cover brightness and contrast control, even if you want to certainly call it so. Exposure (brightness and contrast) control is an inherent part of photography and not something you can avoid by prohibiting it. The image OP posted has already at least three times been through a likely automatic exposure control, when taken, when printed and when scanned. The automatic exposure control in the scanner obviously failed and that failure is all I have corrected.

I happily defer to your knowledge of photographic terms of art, I'm just not sure the US State Department shares it.  They may have used the term in a much less technical way, possibly in the ignorant layman's way that I use it, and the first the OP would have known (in the old days) is that the image was rejected.  The problem with going toe-to-toe with governments on issues like the minutiae of language is that they don't have to care that you're right, because they've got all the power.

Is it even possible to tell if a photo was adjusted in this way? But I suppose it's not a good idea as I am naturally very pale and the original photo reflects that.

@Peter The correction I made is not lossless, so a forensic scientist will likely be able to detect the changes. With the cost of a forensic analysis of computer images, it is however completely unrealistic to assume that US authorities let the presented visa photographs undergo an analysis on a routinely basis. I don't know which scanning software you used in the first place, but if the scanners auto-exposure fails like here, you can probably even adjust the brightness of the image directly somewhere in the scanning software if that makes you feel more confident the image will be accepted.

Peter asks if it's possible to tell a photo was adjusted. On my Windows computer the properties has camera information on the original, but that's not present after I edit it. But to get down to 1200 x 1200 pixels and under 240 kB you have to edit it, so they're never going to see an unedited picture.
